# Dropdown fecha a cada click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Bom dia Guys,

Tenho um dropdown onde tenho vários checkbox contido nele. Porem quando clico em qualquer checkbox o dropdown seleciona apenas ele e fecha, queria manter o dropdown aberto até terminar minhas escolhas.

Isso seria possivel ? Se sim, como pode ser feito?

Dropdown:

```
$('#userList').append(
                '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ml-2">'+
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="'+data[i].id+'">'+
                    '<label class="custom-control-label" for="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].nome+' '+data[i].sobrenome+'</label>'+
                '</div>'
                );
```

Div do Dropdown:

```
<div  class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 dropdown'>
                    <button class="btn btn-info botao" type='button' id="user" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="user" id="userList">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#userList', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css">

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 dropdown'>
        <button class="btn btn-info botao" type='button' id="user" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu px-4 py-3" aria-labelledby="user" id="userList">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                            <span class="custom-control-description">Opção 1</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                            <span class="custom-control-description">Opção 2</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: teria como postar o código do seu dropdown?

Comment: Postei, usei como id user, alterei na função tbm e não funcionou

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap você está usando?

Comment: A versão é a 4.0.0

Comment: testa ai sem o append pra ver se funciona, se sim depois integra o append.

Comment: Também não funciona :/

Comment: Diego, dê uma verificada aqui no snippet que postei.Para referência estou usando o Chrome em Windows.

Comment: Cara, não sei o que está acontecendo, pois fiz identico ao teu e não funcionou

Comment: Se executar aqui no stackoverflow funciona? se sim pode tentar desativar alguma biblioteca JS sua pra ver se não está influenciando.

Comment: Testei seu exemplo e tbm não foi, agora tenho que descobrir qual bib está influenciando nisto...

Comment: Fora que aqui nem o checkbox aparece... Com a sua aplicação

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98087/discussion-between-diego-correia-de-andrade-and-leonardo-getulio).

Answer (score -1):

O #userList é um select?

Se lhe deres o parametro **multiple**, it works ;)

exemplo

```html
<select multiple >
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="3">France</option>
  <option value="4">Poland</option>
  <option value="5">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: É um dropdown amigo... o #userList é uma div do dropdown, apenas puxo ela para poder levar as info do bd para view com ajax.

Comment: dropdown é só a class que utiliza.. pode por o que quiser la dentro..

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215532/usar-bootstrap-para-multiselect-dropdown-com-checkbox

Comment: Ele está usando [dropdown do Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/), e não um select comum.